# Possible to add an SBS server to an existing domain?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, windows-sbs-2003, virtualization

I've got a box with Windows Server 2008 Std installed, and I've created a virtual PC with Windows 2003 Server SBS on it, and am running it through Virtual Server 2005.

I've set the new 2003 server up using the same domain name credentials as the existing (host) server, and was hoping that they'd 'just talk', sharing the existing set of user details that are set up on the host, across into the 2003 server... but it's not at present.

Is this because I haven't yet configured them correctly, or have I wasted my time because this scenario just will not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884453

Comment: Ah, slight problem:

"The functional level of the domain or forest is incompatible with this operating system" 

"The version of the operating system installed is incompatible with teh current domain functional level. You must upgrade to a newer version of the operating system before this server can become a domain controller in this domain."

Rats.

Comment: You need to raise the domain and the forest functional level to (at least) Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Oh right, thanks! (Where do I do that??)